# Theorems which later turned out to be vacuous

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Has it ever happened that a theorem of the form

> If $P$, then $Q$

was proven and published, perhaps with great difficulty, only for someone to realize later that the condition $P$ of the theorem is never satisfied, or, worse, that the conclusion $Q$ of the implication is false?

For example, if the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis were disproved tomorrow, I would have a large supply of examples on my hands, as so many results are conditional on GRH. But surely, this must have happened before, in the long history of mathematics?

Comment: You make it sound as if the proof of "if P then Q" was wasted effort. But maybe the proof of the stronger result "if P then 0 = 1" is **based on** the proof of the partial result "if P then Q"?

Comment: Yes, I agree with bof.  If $Q$ is known to be false, then proving $P\rightarrow Q$ gives you some useful information that is exactly what you mention: $P$ never being satisfied.

Comment: I agree with both of you that many interesting things could still arise out of such a situation, all of which could add to the charm of such an example. Presumaby, the effort would be completely wasted only if $Q$ were later proven to be false.

Comment: Possible urban myth, S. T. Yau once said (he really said it, that's not the myth part, I was there) that there had been a Ph. D. dissertation on Holder continuous functions with exponent above $1.$ The trouble being that all such functions are constant.

Comment: The second example in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/473039/137524) seems to qualify.

Comment: Somewhere on the internet there is a recording of Mandelbrot discussing something like this regarding the Navier-Stokes equations, where a theorem was proved about a set which might have been empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the proof of FLT, was essential the fact that nontrivial FLT solution $\implies$ $\exists$ weird elliptical curve. Wiles proved that  there isn't weird elliptical curve. See [A question on FLT and Taniyama Shimura](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/a-question-on-flt-and-taniyama-shimura).

Comment: Dear Martín: This is not really what I am looking for. In this case, what would be the theorem which turned out to be vacuous? See Will's comment for an example of the type of situation that I am curious about. Best,